# SQL Server: Eliminate duplicates based on two columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following table in SQL Server 2012:

[image]

I need to select distinct rows and only whose contact equal to "Own". The result should like this:

[image]

I tried the following query:

```
with cte as
(
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by contact order by SiteNum) rn,
        SiteNum, SiteAdd, Description, Contact
    from 
        Name
)
select * 
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

I am not sure if it can be accomplished using different approach like temp table or where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to partition by `SiteNum` and order by the `Contact`, which is the opposite of what you were doing.  But other than this, your approach seems on the right track.  Try this query:

```
with cte as
(
    select row_number() over (partition by SiteNum
        order by case when Contact = 'Own' then 0 else 1 end) rn,
        SiteNum, SiteAdd, Description, Contact
    from Name
)
select * from cte 
where rn = 1
```

Note that I used a `CASE` expression for the `ORDER BY` clause which explicitly checks for a contact called 'Own'.  We could have tried using `MIN()` or `MAX()` and relied on non matching records having `NULL`, but this could lead to problems later on should your table have other contact values besides 'Own'.

Answer (score 0):

This where clause should give you what you are expecting

```
Select DISTINCT SiteAdd from table where Contact = 'Own'
```

You can put the distinct on the entire row also, in case there are duplicate rows.

```
Select DISTINCT * from table where Contact = 'Own'
```

Your original query will work based on the logic. Just change the TYPO :

> wehre rn = 1 to where rn=1

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I include where contact = 'Own' I won't be getting back row  number 2 (SiteNum 2).